# How to display dynamically added form data in a table in a different webpage when the data is saved in the local storage using purely javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a school project in which I'm creating web pages to allow users to input and then display it on another page. I am only using JavaScript, HTML and CSS for the web pages.

On the "Create An Event" page there is a form. I have saved all the input into local storage but now I am not sure how to retrieve the data to display it on the "Events Created" page (which shows the past events that the user has created).

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", docIsReady);
var eventHist;

function docIsReady() {
    eventHist = localStorage.getItem("createEvent");

    if (eventHist == null) {
        eventHist = [];
    } else {
        eventHist = JSON.parse(eventHist);
    }

    //building of the table
    for (var i = 0; i < eventHist.length; i++) {
        var row = document.getElementById("list").insertRow(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        cell1.innerHTML = eventHist[i].name;
        cell2.innerHTML = eventHist[i].positions;
        cell3.innerHTML = eventHist[i].venue;
        cell4.innerHTML = eventHist[i].date;
        cell5.innerHTML = eventHist[i].timeStart;
        cell6.innerHTML = eventHist[i].timeEnd;
    }
}

function addHistory() {
    var obj;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    if (!checkExisting(name)) {
        var positions = document.getElementById("pos").value;
        var venue = document.getElementById("venue").value;
        var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
        var starttime = document.getElementById("timeStart").value;
        var endtime = document.getElementById("timeEnd").value;

        obj = {
            "name": name,
            "venue": venue,
            "date": date,
            "timeStart": starttime,
            "timeEnd": endtime
        };
        eventHist.push(obj)
        localStorage.setItem("createEvent", JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
    //add to table
    var row = document.getElementById("list").insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    cell1.innerHTML = obj.name;
    cell2.innerHTML = obj.positions;
    cell3.innerHTML = obj.venue;
    cell4.innerHTML = obj.date;
    cell5.innerHTML = obj.timeStart;
    cell6.innerHTML = obj.timeEnd;
}

function sortTable() {
    eventHist.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
        if (obj1.date > obj2.date)
            return 1;
        else if (obj1.date < obj2.date)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    });
    console.log("Sorted");

    //reload table
    var tableRow = document.querySelectorAll("#list tr");
    console.log(tableRow);
    console.log("no of rows=" + tableRow.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < eventHist.length; i++) {
        var row = document.getElementById("list").insertRow(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        cell1.innerHTML = eventHist[i].name;
        cell2.innerHTML = eventHist[i].positions;
        cell3.innerHTML = eventHist[i].venue;
        cell4.innerHTML = eventHist[i].date;
        cell5.innerHTML = eventHist[i].timeStart;
        cell6.innerHTML = eventHist[i].timeEnd;
    }
    document.getElementById("list").style.display = "table";
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table border="1px" id="list" onload="addRow();">
    <tr>
        <th>Name of event</th>
        <th>Positions</th>
        <th>Venue</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>End Time</th>
        <!--<th>Points Awarded</th>-->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so what is the problem ?

Comment: I am unable to display the data from the local storage in the table.